# Excel splitting of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've text something like this in text file (each entry on new line).

```
99212 OFFICE O/P EST SF 10-19 MIN
99213 OFFICE O/P EST LOW 20-29 MIN
```

I want to put this information in csv and expecting something like this

```
"99212", "OFFICE O/P EST SF 10-19 MIN"
"99213", "OFFICE O/P EST LOW 20-29 MIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in column A:

```
=LET(a,TOCOL(A:A,1),
 MAP(a, LAMBDA(x,
""""&TEXTJOIN(""",""",,TEXTBEFORE(x," ",1),TEXTAFTER(x," ",1))))&"""")
```